# Spark Dataframe - Merge Nested Columns into one

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, aws-glue

I'm trying to merge a dataframe that has multiple nested struct columns into one single struct column. Here's a same schema

Before:

```
|- column_1
|- column_2
|- column_3
|- nested_details_1
   |- a
   |- b
   |- c
|- nested_details_2
   |- d
   |- e
   |- f
```

Desired after:

```
|- column_1
|- column_2
|- column_3
|- nested_details
   |- a
   |- b
   |- c
   |- d
   |- e
   |- f
```

Visually I can see what needs to be done, but is there a function with data frames to merge columns for me? If it makes any difference I am using AWS Glue Dynamic Dataframe but I can convert easily enough to a normal data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### pyspark

I managed to merge 2 structs using the [pyspark `struct` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.struct.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct) like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col, expr

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

input_df = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        1 as column_1,
        2 as column_2,
        3 as column_3,
        named_struct("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3) as nested_details_1,
        named_struct("d", 4, "e", 5, "f", 6) as nested_details_2
""")
merged_df = input_df.select(
    col("column_1"),
    col("column_2"),
    col("column_3"),
    struct(col("nested_details_1.*"),col("nested_details_2.*")).alias("nested_details")
)
merged_df.printSchema()
merged_df.show()
merged_df.select(expr("typeof(nested_details)")).show(truncate=False)
```

above prints

```
root
 |-- column_1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- column_2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- column_3: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- nested_details: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- c: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- d: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- e: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- f: integer (nullable = false)

+--------+--------+--------+------------------+
|column_1|column_2|column_3|    nested_details|
+--------+--------+--------+------------------+
|       1|       2|       3|{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}|
+--------+--------+--------+------------------+

+-------------------------------------------+
|typeof(nested_details)                     |
+-------------------------------------------+
|struct<a:int,b:int,c:int,d:int,e:int,f:int>|
+-------------------------------------------+
```

#### Spark SQL

same can be achieved with SQL also using [SQL `struct` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#struct) like this:

```sql
with input as (
SELECT 
    1 as column_1,
    2 as column_2,
    3 as column_3,
    named_struct("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3) as nested_details_1,
    named_struct("d", 4, "e", 5, "f", 6) as nested_details_2 
)
SELECT 
    column_1,
    column_2, 
    column_3, 
    struct(nested_details_1.*, nested_details_2.*) as nested_details
FROM input
```